# Visual Studio 2022 hangs when open Razor file

Tags: razor, blazor, freeze, visual-studio-2022

Created a stock Blazor project (Client or Server side, both do it).

When I open the _Imports.razor, not a problem.
Open NavMenu.razor, a problem.

The IDE opens the file, displays formatted Razor and after a couple of seconds just hangs, CPU usage for devenv.exe goes 50% and stays there until End Task.

Any idea how to fix this? The IDE should not hang when I try and work with a Razor file.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the effort by these guys, changing the IDE font from 'Cascadia Mono' to Consolas sorted the problem:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-487353/Visual-Studio-2022-stops-responding-when-used-with-Resharper

(Note: Not using Resharper, stock VS2022 install)